# What if one is served a shmita product that is not shmita kosher? Eat it or throw it?

Tags: halacha, food, shmita

If one is served a product from which Shmita was not kept- (fruit, or other) is it permissible or even recommended to eat it since the product will otherwise be thrown to the trash? The products have inherent holiness but a lav was done with it.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "shmita was not kept"?  Was it grown and harvested by a Jew on Jewish owned land?  Was it grown under heter mechira?  Was it grown by non-Jews on land they occupy because they conquered it by force ( most Arab owned land in Israel ), i.e. y'vul nochri?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes whatever you find to be non shmita product.